# Using Matplotlib in Python, how to get a list of all drawn plt.scatter()?

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

When using matplotlib, you can easily access whatever curves you have drawn using `plt.plot()` by looking in the `ax.lines` list and remove n-th curve like so: `del ax.lines[n]`.

Does the equivalent exist for `plt.scatter()`? After drawing several scatters the `ax.lines` is still empty so there must be another list somewhere.

For context, I am building a measurement interface using Qt Designer where the user might want to discard previous curves, so being able to choose via such a list which one is deleted (instead of clearing everything) is good.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such problems you may first just print out the return type of the object you deal with.

```
scatter = plt.scatter(x,y)
print(type(scatter))
```

This prints `<class 'matplotlib.collections.PathCollection'>`. From the name of the object we might deduce that the scatter is part of the axes' collections,

```
ax.collections
```

Indeed,

```
print(scatter)
print(plt.gca().collections[0])
```

print the same object.

Comment: Thank you for your help! `del`eting one of these collections erased the associated scatter.
Is `print(type())` commonly used to find where "complex objects" store their data? I only started Python two weeks ago so any good reflex is good for the taking.

Comment: Yes, `type` is a very useful tool to explore a framework or library. You may print the type, then go to find that type in the documentation or the source code to see what options you have using that object.